# Replacing ".jpg" thumbnail handler

Tags: windows, windows-10, thumbnails, windows-shell, thumbnail-handler

I wrote a new thumbnail handler for windows 10. When I apply it on my custom ".mic" files (which are renamed ".jpg" files) the handler works well. However, for some reason the handler is not being called at all for ".jpg" files.

These are the entries I add to the registry during "DllRegisterServer":

```
    // List of registry entries we want to create
    const REGISTRY_ENTRY rgRegistryEntries[] =
    {
        { HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\" SZ_CLSID_MYTHUMBHANDLER,                         REG_SZ,   NULL,               SZ_XDRVTHUMBHANDLER },
        { HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\" SZ_CLSID_MYTHUMBHANDLER L"\\InProcServer32",     REG_SZ,   NULL,               szModuleName },
        { HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\" SZ_CLSID_MYTHUMBHANDLER L"\\InProcServer32",     REG_SZ,   L"ThreadingModel",  L"Apartment" },
        { HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,   L"Software\\Classes\\.mic\\ShellEx\\{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}" ,  REG_SZ,   NULL,               SZ_CLSID_MYTHUMBHANDLER },
        { HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,   L"Software\\Classes\\.jpg\\ShellEx\\{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}" ,  REG_SZ,   NULL,               SZ_CLSID_MYTHUMBHANDLER },
    };

    hr = S_OK;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(rgRegistryEntries) && SUCCEEDED(hr); i++)
    {
        hr = CreateRegKeyAndSetValue(&rgRegistryEntries[i]);
    }
```

When I tried testing my handler with the "ThumbnailProvider.exe" utility (provided with windows SDK), it works well. I ran the utility with a ".jpg" file, and my handler was successfully called.

Why is my handler not being called by explorer?

EDIT:
On some other PC, it seems to work perfectly. My original registration code works well and my handler is being called for "jpg" files. Both PCs have windows 10, and in fact they are VMs using the same base image.

EDIT:
I noticed that my handler is being called for some ".jpg" files, on others it doesn't. I may be wrong here, but the major difference that I have noticed between the files is the "Resolution Unit" property. For the working files there was no value for this property, for the non-working files, the value for this property is "2". I get the same behavior on all my PCs.
Any idea how this property affects the thumbnail handler being called? If it is not the "Resolution Unit" property, what can be the difference which causes it?

Comment: The default value for Software\\Classes\\.jpg usually contains "jpegfile" (it could be anything else), so the shell will look into Software\\Classes\\jpegfile instead, if that's the case. Also make sure HKCU doesn't override anything. For information, HKCR is a combined view of HKLM+HKCU Software\\Classes.

Comment: I did as you said, I added it to both "jpegfile" and ".jpeg". I see all of them configured with my handler under HKCR. However, my handler is still not being called for ".jpg" files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the reason why my thumbnail handler is not being called on some of the ".jpg" files. It seems that some jpg images have an embedded thumbnail inside them. So for these files no thumbnail handler is being called at all.
I used `exiftool` utility to read the image properties, in the output I see the following lines:
`Photoshop Thumbnail             : (Binary data 8015 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 8015 bytes, use -b option to extract)`

I used `exiftool` to remove the thumbnails from the file. Once I did that, my handler was successfully called for this image.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110(v=vs.85).aspx) that you need to call `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0)` when you register a new extension handler object.

> If you do not call SHChangeNotify, the change might not be recognized
>   until the system is rebooted.

On my machine the Microsoft handler is registered as a generic handler under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image` and I believe that key is supposed to have a lower priority but it might be worth investigating. As noted in the comments by Simon, the shell reads from HKCR and that is a combined view where HKEY_CURRENT_USER can override HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE so you should also make sure nothing is set for your specific user.

Going into [semi-documented](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918165/you-may-experience-problems-in-windows-explorer-or-in-the-windows-shel) territory we see that Explorer may cache some CLSID information under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Cached` and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Cached` so if all else fails you could try to delete these keys (at least the one under HKCU should be safe to delete).

Comment: My handler is based on the "Recipe" sample from windows SDK, so I already have the call to `SHChangeNotify`. I tried deleting the semi-documented caches you have mentioned, but it still doesn't work. Reboots also didn't help. I also tried it with @SimonMourier suggestion.

Comment: I also wanted to try and modify `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image`, but this key is read-only and cannot be modified.

Comment: Some keys are owned by System/Trusted Installer and you need to take ownership of the key before you can change the ACL.

Comment: I have modified `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\image` as you said. In can see now that my handler is being called for ".png" files, but for some reason it is still not being called for ".jpg" files.

Comment: Try Process Monitor and look at all the keys Explorer uses to find the handler...

Comment: It is difficult to track as there is a massive registry activity. I have 2 ".jpg" files, on one file my handler is called and on the other it doesn't. For both files I see in procmon that the key `HKCR\.jpg\ShellEx\{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}\(Default)` is being accessed and the CLSID of my handler is retrieved. However, only for the working file explorer continues to read `HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9D36FFEC-3982-487B-871A-CE1F69BDBC49}` which is the CLSID of my handler.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this didn't solve my exact problem but you reminded me to check SystemFileAssociations to remove the existing (broken) handler.